# Using Beyond Compare４ in MacOS with cmd for svn

Tags: svn, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I am using the Cornerstone.

The version of `Beyond Compare` is 4.2.1 (build 22354).

How to using the command line to open `Beyond Compare` for svn.

I want to set the `Beyond Compare` as the diff tool for svn.

> Comparing Revisions in the Timeline View
>   To compare two revisions in the timeline view:
>   Select the first revision by clicking the revision in the timeline.
>   Select the second revision by holding down the ⌘ key while clicking the revision.
>   The files are compared in the compare view underneath the timeline. The earlier revision is always displayed on the left.
>   Folders cannot be compared.

This method is OK.

https://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/helpbook/pages/working/history/timeline/comparing.html

I don't know how to use `AppleScript`.

Answer (score 2):

There are instructions for configuring Beyond Compare as Cornerstone's diff tool [right on the BC website](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs_osx)

> In Cornerstone, you can specify a custom external compare script.
>
> Launch Beyond Compare, go to the Beyond Compare menu and run Install Command Line Tools.
>
> #### DIFF
>
> Create an AppleScript wrapper for use by Cornerstone:

```
-- Cornerstone executes the script as:
-- /path/to/tool <original> <modified>
--
on run argv
  set original_path to (item 1 of argv)
  set modified_path to (item 3 of argv)
  do shell script "/usr/local/bin/bcomp \"" & original_path & "\" \"" & modified_path & "\""
end run
```

> Set in **Preferences | General | External compare tool | Other Script...**

Open the AppleScript editor, paste in the script above, save the file and then point BC at the file you just created.

Comment: I save the file and use it in the Cornerstone. I use the script in the cornerstone, then the error "error: sh: /usr/local/bin/bcomp: No such file or directory (127)" shows me.   >"then point BC at the file you just created. " How to do it?

Comment: Do you have the path to bcomp correct in the script? Do you have the path to your script correct in the beyond compare settings?

Comment: It's OK now. Because I don't put the `Beyond Compare' to the application folder.  The 'Beyond Compare` stay in the download folder. I put the `Beyond Compare` to the application folder.  Then it works well.

Comment: When I close the `Beyond compare`  the alert is "The command exits when the state is nonzero". How to fix it?

Comment: BC doesn't install to /usr/local/bin by default; if you use the **Beyond Compare** > **Install Command Line Tools...** menu item it will.  The AppleScript should refer to that; don't point directly at the bcomp in the .app bundle

Answer (score 0):

set beyond compare as the diff editor/tool from the svn preferences.

Comment: I don't see the `beyond compare` in the menu.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have SVN installed on my (this) macintosh. However I've set Beyond Compare on a PC, and it was the SVN properties/configuration somewhere. I had to type in the file path/name. Then when you use SVN to diff two files, beyond compare will be used.

Comment: Cornerstone, preferences, external compare tool, a select menu.

Comment: oh, sorry. I checked cornerstone documentation and beyond compare is not listed as a supported diff tool. Wacky though: I wonder if "preferences | locations | use shared subversion configuration" could access the configuration set using another svn tool. Or go into the .subversion file and mess with the config - but touching that folder is not recommended.

Comment: I am a newbie. I can't do the difficult thing. Thank you.

Comment: @jiexishede you won't move past "newbie" stage until you start *trying* the "difficult thing". You might even surprise yourself by being successful after an attempt or two. And sometimes the "difficult thing" is only a simple web search away.

Answer (score 0):

"The command exits when the state is nonzero"
You can modify the script from '/usr/local/bin/bcomp' to '/usr/local/bin/bcompare'